# Update Table data with CTE in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Am trying to update the data discrepancies in one table from the other table using the below update statement.

```
UPDATE edw_csd_etl_ds_instance_detail xcsd1
   SET  xcsd1.install_location_id = xservice1.install_location_id,
        xcsd1.install_site_flag = xservice1.install_site_flag,
        xcsd1.party_site_id = xservice1.party_site_id,
        xcsd1.organization_id = xservice1.organization_id,
        xcsd1.item_type_flag = xservice1.item_type_flag,
        xcsd1.po_number = xservice1.po_number
FROM (
WITH
instance_data AS ( SELECT instance_id,
               install_location_id,
               install_site_flag,
               party_site_id,
               organization_id,
               item_type_flag,
               po_number
          FROM edw_service_etl_ds_instance_detail xservice
         WHERE     xservice.instance_last_update_date >=
                      '2021-11-24 00:00:00.000'
               AND xservice.instance_last_update_date <=
                      '2021-11-25 00:00:00.000'
        MINUS
        SELECT instance_id,
               install_location_id,
               install_site_flag,
               party_site_id,
               organization_id,
               item_type_flag,
               po_number
          FROM edw_csd_etl_ds_instance_detail xcsd
         WHERE     xcsd.instance_last_update_date >=
                      '2021-11-24 00:00:00.000'
               AND xcsd.instance_last_update_date <=
                      '2021-11-25 00:00:00.000')
SELECT idata.* FROM instance_data idata) AS xservice1
WHERE xcsd1.instance_id = xservice1.instance_id;
```

Though it is showing me as 1000 number of records, if I run the MINUS query still i can see the descrepencies.

Is there any issue with my query? Can someone help me.

Thanks,
Sudarshan

Comment: Do any of those columns have null values in either table?

Comment: Yeah Nick.. there were millions of records in those tables. So possible chance of those columns can be NULL

Comment: Without access to your data it's not easy to help so I think you'll need to investigate this yourself - but I would look at a) when you run the update is it actually showing it is updating records? b) after the update is the table showing the update values that you expect? c) assuming you have time travel enabled, if you run the minus query for before and after the update, is it returning different results and what are the differences?

Comment: Will check on the data and get back to you Nick... Thank you

Comment: I would always start 1 with success record which got updated Vs 1 which did got captured. Then see mismatches why CTE did not capture and does CTE should be  edw_csd_etl_ds_instance_detail xcsd  - edw_service_etl_ds_instance_detail xservice because you are updating edw_csd_etl_ds_instance_detail table?